# UIPickerView test case breaks if using viewForRow

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I have a picker view and want to select 8 - Sohail or 9 - Sohail but i am unable to find XCElement using XCUIElementQuery. When I overrided 'pickerView - viewForRow' method for defining our own custom view, XCUIElementQuery unable to find it. Code is here for UIPickerView. Without overriding viewForRow it works fine.

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    var i : String?
    i = "\(row) - Sohail"
    return i
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    print("\(row) - Sohail")
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    let pickerLabel = UILabel()

    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    pickerLabel.text = "\(row) - Sohail"
    return pickerLabel
}
```

And for UI test case

```
func testPicker(){

    let app = XCUIApplication()

//        print(app.pickerWheels.count)
//        app.descendantsMatchingType(.PickerWheel)["1 - Sohail"].tap()
//        print(app.pickerWheels.element)
//        app.pickerWheels.elementBoundByIndex(0).swipeUp()

    app.pickerWheels.element.adjustToPickerWheelValue("9 - Sohail")

    sleep(2)

//        app.pickerWheels["0 - Sohail"].tap()
//        app.pickerWheels["8 - Sohail"].tap()

}
```

I am getting this failure message.

`UI Testing Failure - Internal error: unable to find current value '0 - Sohail, 1 of 10' in possible values 0 - Sohail, 1 - Sohail, 2 - Sohail, 3 - Sohail, 4 - Sohail, 5 - Sohail, 6 - Sohail, 7 - Sohail, 8 - Sohail, 9 - Sohail for the picker wheel "0 - Sohail, 1 of 10" PickerWheel`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `accessibilityValue` of the rows in your picker is defined as the "currentValue" shown in the error, not what you actually read. Bug report [on OpenRadar here](http://www.openradar.me/22918650).